# SQL Server stored procedure calls multiple stored procedure and fails to return result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure (`USA2YearPremiumAnalysis`) that calls two variations of another stored procedure (`2YearPremiumAnalysisByState`) with different variables.

So the code for SP-Parent looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USA2YearPremiumAnalysis
   @ContractYear1 INT
   , @importDate1 DATETIME
   , @importDate2 DATETIME
   , @EnrollmentYear1 INT
   , @EnrollmentYear2 INT
   , @EnrollmentMonth1 INT
   , @EnrollmentMonth2 INT
AS
   EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
   @ContractYear1, 
   @importDate1, @importDate2, 
   @EnrollmentYear1, @EnrollmentYear2, 
   @EnrollmentMonth1, @EnrollmentMonth2,
   0

   EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
   @ContractYear1, 
   @importDate1, @importDate2, 
   @EnrollmentYear1, @EnrollmentYear2, 
   @EnrollmentMonth1, @EnrollmentMonth2, 
   1
GO
```

This is not returning any data. Yet, if I call:

```
   EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
   @ContractYear1, 
   @importDate1, @importDate2, 
   @EnrollmentYear1, @EnrollmentYear2, 
   @EnrollmentMonth1, @EnrollmentMonth2,
   0

   EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
   @ContractYear1, 
   @importDate1, @importDate2, 
   @EnrollmentYear1, @EnrollmentYear2, 
   @EnrollmentMonth1, @EnrollmentMonth2, 
   1
```

I get what I expect.

The Child proc is fairly complex. It works when you call the procedure with the same variables that are passed into the parent proc.

How do I get the Parent procedure to return the 2 resulting tables?

Comment: Do your child procs return `int` or are you expecting to get a table back?

Comment: The Child procs return tables.

Comment: Your code should return the result set(s) from the child sp's. What does `SP-Child` look like?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I updated the question to reflect the actual sql for the parent procedure. If you think it is necessary, I can add the child proc (VERY Long).

Comment: I don't see any errors in there. It must be somewhere else. Either in the child sp or in calling the parent sp. You could try to replace the child sp's with something really simple and see if that works like `create procedure ChildProc @I int as select @I as I` and use `ChildProc` in another sp twice. If that works for you (does for me) you should look for the error in your child sp.

Comment: Thank you @MikaelEriksson. Your suggestion directed me to examine the child proc. I explained my error fully in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child procedure is a very long multi-step procedure written dynamically. There were two issues, one was a problem within the child procedure that was causing the dynamic sql to be set to NULL. The second was the way I was testing my top level problem: I had typed in different numbers for the child procedure when I was running them manually and thus, was getting fooled into thinking they were working.

If I had done this, I would have known my problem was immediately in the child procs:

```
DECLARE @ContractYear1 INT = 2011
DECLARE @importDate1 DATETIME = '7/27/2011 12:00:00 AM'
DECLARE @importDate2 DATETIME = '6/7/2010 12:00:00 AM'
DECLARE @EnrollmentYear1 INT = 2011
DECLARE @EnrollmentYear2 INT = 2010
DECLARE @EnrollmentMonth1 INT = 7
DECLARE @EnrollmentMonth2 INT = 9

--EXEC MAInfo.USA2YearPremiumAnalysis @ContractYear1, -- int
--    @importDate1, -- datetime
--    @importDate2, -- datetime
--    @EnrollmentYear1, -- int
--    @EnrollmentYear2, -- int
--    @EnrollmentMonth1, -- int
--    @EnrollmentMonth2-- int

EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
    @ContractYear1, 
    @importDate1, -- datetime
    @importDate2, -- datetime
    @EnrollmentYear1, -- int
    @EnrollmentYear2, -- int
    @EnrollmentMonth1, -- int
    @EnrollmentMonth2,
    0

EXECUTE MAInfo.[2YearPremiumAnalysisByState] 
    @ContractYear1, 
    @importDate1, @importDate2, 
    @EnrollmentYear1, @EnrollmentYear2, 
    @EnrollmentMonth1, @EnrollmentMonth2, 
    1
```

Thank you for your time and sorry for the goose chase!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go over this extensive article from Erland titled 'How to Share Data between Stored Procedures' - http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

The article is well explained with examples for each option. Hope you would find it useful.